# Database object is disposed while executing a task

Tags: asynchronous, callback, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-2.0

This is the flow I am working towards,

- Make a call to web api
- Web api will immediately return OK
- Web api will do some work in background

This is what I have achieved so far,

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PremController : Controller
    {
        private readonly myDbContext _context;

        public PremController(myDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ => GetProducts());

        }

        private void GetProducts()
        {
            var productUrls = _context.Products.Select(p => p.Url).ToArrayAsync();
        }

        static Task Delay(int milliseconds)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            new Timer(_ => tcs.SetResult(null)).Change(milliseconds, -1);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting error that myDbContext is disposed off before newly created task has completed. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're creating a fire-and-forget task, with no synchronization context. If you awaited `DoWork()` directly, synchronization context would be preserved, ensuring context is not disposed. More specifically, the task you're creating runs outside the lifetime of your context, as defined by the DI container (most likely request-scoped). As soon as the request completes, the context is disposed, killing the work your task is trying to complete outside the request.

Long and short, this is bad design for a number of reasons. If you need to do "background" work, that should be offloaded to an entirely different process, not just a new thread. The code that runs there should be responsible for maintaining its own context, unaffected by what's going on in your web app. `Task.Run`/`Task.Factory.StartNew` is extremely bad for web applications since there's a finite thread pool, and starting up new threads from that pool reduces your server's total load capacity.

If you find yourself wanting to spin up a new thread in a web application, don't. It's almost universally wrong. Instead, schedule the work using a background processing solution like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or similar.